# How to perform nested eval with same binding?

Tags: ruby

Writing something like a templating engine and I'd like included files to add variables to the base file. Things do not work as expected though. My observations of `eval` are as follows:

```
[23] pry(main)> b = binding
=> #<Binding:0x000055ca9d13ad68>
[24] pry(main)> eval('eval("ddd=1", b); ddd', b)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ddd' for main:Object
from (pry):1:in `__pry__'
[25] pry(main)> eval('eval("ddd=1", b); ddd', b)
=> 1
```

Why does the first call fail? My expectation was that the nested `eval` will set the variable in the binding and then it will be visible outside. In fact it is visible in the binding only after.

Any advice how to allow nested `eval` to set variables accessible from the code of the outer `eval`?

Comment: There is no way to leak the local variable to the outer binding.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I'm not leaking them in outer binding. `eval` and nested `eval` both specify the same binding. So there is only one binding. Variables **do** get inserted into that binding but never visible to the outer `eval` (even though it uses the same binding).

Comment: Oh, indeed. I seem to know why, though, will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole `'eval("ddd=1", b); ddd'` comes to the ruby parser as somewhat like:

```
some_func(...)
ddd
```

It does not know that `some_func` might define the local variable and raises `NameError` exactly as the code above does.

The code below would work:

```
b = binding
eval('eval("ddd=1", b); b.local_variable_get(:ddd)', b)
```

Here the parser is satisfied since there is no undefined locals upfront.

Comment: Another way to look at this is, see the difference in output by inserting `p local_variables; p b.local_variables` after the semicolon.

Comment: On the one hand, the parser thinks that `ddd` is not defined locally; on the other hand, the method *has* been added to the current binding.

Comment: Is there any way to reset this state? I would like users to write just `varibable_name` instead of using methods like `local_variable_get`.

Comment: What state? Besides it is definitely not the best idea to just `eval` whatever the user input is, the whole workflow is absolutely not clear from the question as it is stated.

Comment: @akostadinov Your question states nothing about user input, so I don't know how to answer this.

Comment: User is writing a template and can include files within it for reusing snippets. There is no concern about security because all code is from same author. But I assume, once parsed, there is no way to parse again and continue from where it included the other file. Thank you.